# Adding a Rule for User ID

Tags: jquery

I have 1 form that is used to create a user and update a user. They also use the same jQuery validation code and I want to add in an if statement somewhere so that if the hidden field with the id of user_id is set then it adds a rule to verify that the value is a digit. I obviously already only need this to be done if the update on a user is being performed. Any ideas?

Comment: If it's a hidden input, does it really need to be validated on the client side? how would the user fix it if it's hidden? This particular validation should probably happen on the server.

Comment: I'm just anal about these sort of things. Always assume the worst case scenario.

Comment: Sure, i'm just trying to figure out how you would handle that validation failing.  If it failed, that means the user edited the source and changed it. If they are proficient enough to do that, they may be proficient enough to modify your js and disable the validation too.

Comment: I still have php validating the form but I'd rather verify I'm getting the expected values before I even validate on the backend.

Comment: What validation plugin are you using? Wouldn't you just have to add the appropriate class for the rule that you want the field to follow?

Comment: The one found here. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Oh also you need to change this option: `ignore: ":hidden"` to "" i'm guessing.

Comment: Wow nice guess, but what about the if statement though because it'll only exist on the update.